# Why can I not set right property in vb

Tags: vb.net

I want my form to appear at the right edge of my screen 
but I not use since Right is readonly .Is there a solution for this?

```
Right= My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Right
```

Comment: Code seems right. Need more information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used following and it worked

```
Left= My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Right -Width
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim x As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Right - Me.Width
    Dim y As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Bottom / 2 - Me.Height / 2
    Me.Location = New Point(x, y)
End Sub
```

The Y-Coordinate is not much specified in your question, so I took it as the center..!
Basically you need to subtract the width of the form from the right edge, only then it will appear as you wanted.

Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

We won't know why until you give us more information such as an error message.

```
Dim nRight As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Right
```

works just fine.

Comment: If you're trying to change the size or location of the form, use the `Location` property. Alternately you can use `Width` and `Height`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Location` property instead.

Comment: But it might be error prone to set location i mean it might not apear proper right

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the form to the right edge of the screen by stretching the form, you can use something like this:

```
Me.Width = Me.Width + My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Right - (Me.Left + Me.Width)
```

If you want to move the form to the right edge of the screen without changing its width, you can use this:

```
Me.Left = Me.Left + My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Right - (Me.Left + Me.Width)
```